# Gatling graph : Inject 100users/seconds with a peak of 500users evey 30 seconds

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I want to inject
100 users/second with a peak of 500 users every 30 seconds

**setup(scn.inject(rampUsers(500) over (30 seconds),
ConstantUsersPerSec(100) during (10 minutes)))**

But using this im getting 60,500 users whereas it should be 60000 with a peak every 30seconds.

Could you please help here?

Answer (score 0):

rampUsers will add users evenly and linearly during 30 seconds. After 30 seconds you will have ended 500 users.
Then ConstantUsersPerSec will add 100 users every second during 10 minutes.

```
ramp - 500 users
constant - 100 users * 10 minutes * 60 = 60000 users
------
60500
```